# Related entity not loaded

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm starting a new entity framework project and I'm defining relations among entities.

I defined this simple entities:

```
[Table("db_owner.Students")]
public partial class User 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? SchoolClassId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SchoolClassId")]
    public SchoolClass SchoolClass { get; set; }
}

[Table("db_owner.SchoolClasses")]
public partial class SchoolClass 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But when I retrieve a Student from the DB the SchoolClass property is null.

I also tried to specify relationship in OnModelCreating method of DBContext definition, but nothing changes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
   .HasOptional(s => s.SchoolClass).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.SchoolClassId);
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your relation property with `virtual` keyword for EF's proxy to be able to overload it:

```
[ForeignKey("SchoolClassId")]
public virtual SchoolClass SchoolClass { get; set; }
```

Also, be sure that context's `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` property value is set to `true` (by default it is).

These two conditions enabling lazy loading of your relations.

If you want explicitly load them, use include mechanism.

Comment: Be careful with lazy loading because if used without care, it can cause huge performance problems. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: Where can I find the property `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`, to check for correct value?

Comment: @davioooh Look at `DbContext.Configuration` property. Then look at `DbContextConfiguration.ProxyCreationEnabled` and `DbContextConfiguration.LazyLoadingEnabled` properties which both set to `true` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework won't load all related entities automatically, because that would cause it to potentially load a significant portion of the database.

You can use the [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220213%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method to specify the relationships that you want to load:

```
myDbContext.Users
    .Include(u => u.SchoolClass)
    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == myId);
```

You can also make the `SchoolClass` property virtual. Assuming that you have lazy loading enabled, this will allow Entity Framework to generate a derived class that will load the related entity when the property is accessed for the first time. Notice, however, that this will cause another database query, while [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220213%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) won't.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy-loading is invoked for navigation properties that are marked as virtual.  Otherwise you must explicitly tell Entity Framework to load the related data.